# Importing github repositories on travis

Tags: python, github, travis-ci

I'm trying to import a github repository in my travis build. I do this by calling

```
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in `.travis.yml`. My requirements file looks like this:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/my_account/repository_test.git@development
git+ssh://git@github.com/my_account/repository_test_ii.git@development
```

This seems to work, because both repositories are listed when I call `pip freeze`. However, when I do:

```
import repository_test
import repository_test_ii
```

the second import fails. Both github repositories have a correct setup.py file, and I can install everything locally without any problem. I ran out of ideas of things to check.

I think the problem is probably with my github repository, I suspect probably the module is being imported under a slightly different name. How can I check this? What other things could I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing an __init__.py file in my github repository making it impossible to import it.